# Fetch an image from Mysql in html with PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my code and I wanted to display an image from DB. I followed some videos and recommendations here on Stack Overflow, but still does not work.

Other values like description, title etc works, so the problem is not in the connection with the DB. 
Thank you.

```
<?php

    $sql= "SELECT * FROM guides WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($num > 0) {
      $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
    ?> 
    <h1 class="title"><?=$row['title']?></h1>
    <?php echo' <img class="header" style="height:400px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( stripslashes($row['photo']) ).'" style="width:100px;"></img>' ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="leftcolumn">
        <h2><?=$row['date']?></h2>
        <div class="card" >
          <div class="clearfix">
            <p class="text" ><?=$row['description']?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
           }
          ?>
```

Comment: Suggestion: Save the image file itself on the web server, then save the path to that image in the database.

Comment: firstly change `echo'` to `echo '`

Comment: an image is a `self-closing` element in HTML so it is `<img... />` rather than `<img...></img>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try and specify the folder containing the given image also. E.g src = “containing_folder/$row[‘photo’]” and see if that works. You can still add your functions to the $row[‘photo’], this was just an example.

Answer (score -3):

mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) this returns an array and you need to loop through the array:

The modified code given below----

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM guides WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($num > 0) {
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?> 
    <h1 class="title"><?=$row['title']?></h1>
    <?php echo' <img class="header" style="height:400px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( stripslashes($row['photo']) ).'" style="width:100px;"></img>' ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="leftcolumn">
        <h2><?=$row['date']?></h2>
        <div class="card" >
          <div class="clearfix">
            <p class="text" ><?=$row['description']?></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
           }
   }
          ?>
```

Comment: You don't need to iterate if only 1 row is being returned.

Comment: Thank you. But still does not work. I used while before but actually I link this page with the main one and the content should be the same. so no need for loop